# NativeScript ios presentViewController response

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am trying to build a custom plugin using this library: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQMediaPickerController

My code like this:

```
let controller = IQMediaPickerController.alloc().init();
controller.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true;
let app = utils.ios.getter(UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication);
app.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(controller, true, null)
```

It's opening the activity but how can I get the result if user choose one file?

I tried like this:

```
controller.didFinishMediaWithInfo = function(res){
   console.dir(res);
}
```

But no luck :( . Anyone can help me please :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use xcode to get output.